# Jquery select all images except those with a certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use lazyload on a page.

The code i have is:

```
$(function() {
    $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

However i want it to ignore all images that have the class "notlazy". How do i put a condition in the selector?

Thanks in advance, 
sorry for this primitive question.

Comment: I'm curious - if you have a `.lazy` class for lazy loading, why not just remove that class for those that don't need it?

Comment: haha @Box9 Indeed lol

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try:

```
$('img.lazy').not('.notlazy')
```

There are a few other ways...

```
$('img.lazy:not(.notlazy)')
$('img.lazy').filter(function() {return !$(this).hasClass('notlazy');});
```

Comment: +1! The first method is probably the fastest (i.e. best), because the native selector engine can jump in.

Comment: Thanks,,  I ended up using $('img:not(.notlazy)').lazyload({}); since there is no point of having a class for lazy and one for not lazy.  Now all images are lazy expect if they have the class notlazy.  THANKS GAIN!!!

Comment: I have a problem with laxyload and fancybox both for wordpress. I want to exclude for beign "lazyied" the img that are in the fancy box. They have no class, but they are child of a div with class "slide". How to exlude theme? The original function is $("<img />").bind("load" ......

Comment: @Kreker - not really space here. Why not ask your own question?

Comment: I had to do this with one child, i.e. select all elements but not the child(ren) with a specific parent, so I ended up using: `$("img.lazy").not($('.image-parent-not-lazy').children()).mouseover( ... );` Maybe this will help others.