# jQuery- make a certain image class unaffected by lazy load

Tags: jquery, css, lazy-loading, image

I have a lazy load plugin that seems to target all images on my page. So when I scroll down, the images only then get displayed.

My problem is that I have an image that changes on click. More specifically, when the 'vote' image is clicked, it is replaced by a different 'voted' image in the exact same location (and of the same size).

When the new 'voted' image is shown, it is initially not displayed even though it appears in the same place. It will only appear as soon as you scroll the page (any direction).

I want to know if there is a way to avoid this? I want the image to be displayed instantly without having to scroll.  I thought to add a class or id to the 'voted' button that ensures the lazy load plugin ignores it.

- I have little detail about the lazy load plugin as I am unsure of how it is actually working since it is included in a template I am using. Although I suspect it targets the img tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) to solve this issue, instead of fiddling with the lazy loading.

The basic idea of CSS sprites is to show different parts of the same image rather than multiple different images.

Comment: Note that sprites is not a CSS construct, but rather a clever use of other CSS features.

Comment: hmm I just tried it, it was a really good idea, but it didn't work. It still required me to scroll for some reason...must be something to do with the lazy loading..thanks for the idea, I've learned something new too

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue I was having here.

The solution is here:

```
$('img.lazy:not(.notlazy)')
```

as shown: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485903/jquery-select-all-images-except-those-with-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) it is good idea to give lazy loaded image a specific class. This way you can easily control which images plugin is binded to. For example:

```
<img class="lazy" src="img/grey.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">
```

Then in you code do:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Since Lazy Load is jQuery plugin you can use [any jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you want.